# How can I split and insert a string into a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert these `IMS080','IMS108','IMS218` values into `temptable` in separate rows, like this:

```
row 1: IMS080
row 2: IMS108
row 3: IMS218
```

**Query :**

```
INSERT INTO #TableName
    SELECT UserID 
    FROM ('IMS080', 'IMS108', 'IMS218')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see `3 strings`, not `a string`. So what's your actually input? `'IMS080','IMS108','IMS218' ` or `IMS080,IMS108,IMS218`  ?

Comment: perhaps this could be useful for your case https://stackoverflow.com/a/2886789/6568632

Comment: You've posted [this question 8 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709133/in-sql-how-to-split-an-select-a-string-which-is-not-present-i-a-table). Please don't post duplicated questions here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In SQL how to split an select a string which is not present i a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709133/in-sql-how-to-split-an-select-a-string-which-is-not-present-i-a-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all the id in one string separated by comma and can split it to each row. This will help you.

```
INSERT INTO #TableName
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS USERID  
FROM 
(
    SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE('IMS080,IMS108,IMS218', ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
)AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use of `union`

```
Insert into #TableName
SELECT 'IMS080' UserID
union 
select 'IMS108' UserID
union 
select 'IMS218' UserID
```

**Edit :**

```
Insert into #TableName
values ('IMS080'), ('IMS108'), ('IMS218')
```

Comment: Why to use "select a.UserID from"? you can directly use values ('IMS080'), ('IMS108'), ('IMS218')

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE #TableName(ID int identity(1,1),userid varchar(50));
    INSERT INTO #TableName
        SELECT value as UserID FROM  STRING_SPLIT('IMS080,IMS108,IMS218',',') ORDER BY value

    SELECT * FROM #TableName

------------
ID  userid
----------
1   IMS080
2   IMS108
3   IMS218
```

Comment: **Note:** `STRING_SPLIT` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2016** and thus might not be available to everyone just yet .....

Comment: this query is given who are using SQL Server 2016 ,i don't know OP using which SQL Server but remember this query is also in use..

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO #TableName
    SELECT UserID 
    FROM  ( VALUES ('IMS080')
                 , ('IMS108')
                 , ('IMS218')
         ) AS X (UserId)
```